# I am trying to figure out how to make my functions run one after another... but it is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a very simple text based adventure game using javascript. I am very new and I feel this would be a great was to work with some of the functions, variables, and if-else statements. I have written some code to prompt the screen to ask for age, and give a result.

```
confirm("Ready to play?");
var age = prompt("How old are you?");
if (age >= 18) {
    document.write(" "); 
} else {
    document.write("You're less than 18? You better just stay home.");
}

document.write("<button> Sounds like you're ready.</button>");

var gender = prompt("Male","Female");
if(gender = "Male") {
    document.write("Sounds good!");
} else if(gender = "Female") {
    document.write("Sounds good!");
} else if {
    document.write("You're a damn liar");
    };
};
```

If I run just the top half of the code, everything will run just fine. But if I try to run the gender prompt, alongside the original code, it will run nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: This appears to be Javascript, not Java.

Comment: And you need to use ==, not = to check for equality

Comment: Thank you! It's the simple stuff that I'm missing:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
confirm("Ready to play?");
var age = prompt("How old are you?");
if (age >= 18) {
    document.write(" "); 
} else {
    document.write("You're less than 18? You better just stay home.");
}

document.write("<button> Sounds like you're ready.</button>");

var gender = prompt("Are you Male or Female?");
if(gender == "Male") {
    document.write("Sounds good!");
} else if(gender == "Female") {
    document.write("Sounds good!");
} else {
    document.write("You lie...");
}
```

Basically, you need to replace `=` with `==` or `===`. And a `prompt()` only takes one argument.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out! It is much appreciated.

Comment: If the code worked, press the check mark under the arrow buttons to mark my answer as correct.